# Locate upper case characters in SQL Server database field

Tags: sql-server

I need to locate rows in a database table that have a field with an upper case value.

```
E.g.: select * from Cust where Surname like 'COnTAiNS UpPERcASE VaLUeS'
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

AJ

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do a binary comparison using:

```
select *
from Cust
where cast(Surname as varbinary(120)) != cast(lower(Surname) as varbinary(120))
```

Comment: You could also do a similar thing and just change the collation: `WHERE Surname COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS != lower(Surname)`

Comment: Easy fix but this returns rows with at least one upper case value, not only upper case as per the question.

Comment: @Dinerdo - the question was edited from `'UPPERCASE VALUES ONLY'` to `'COnTAiNS UpPERcASE VaLUeS'`

Answer (score 6):

Another way

```
SELECT *
FROM Cust
WHERE Surname NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
```

Answer (score 2):

This is work for me

```
SELECT * FROM agents 
WHERE  email REGEXP BINARY  '[A-Z]'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT 
 CASE WHEN BINARY_CHECKSUM('yourStriNg') = BINARY_CHECKSUM(LOWER('yourStriNg')) 
     THEN 0 
     ELSE 1 
 END
```

....

Rest of SQL statement

Answer (score 1):

This may be oversimplifying, but works for my use cases:

```
SELECT *
FROM Cust
WHERE Surname != LOWER(Surname)
```

Comment: It does not work on MySql v5.6.10
MySql ignore case on this kind of match.

Comment: This works perfectly in Postgres 14. I appreciate the simplicity of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to extract only capital letter from given string value:

```
Declare @Val Varchar(100)
Set @Val='MicrosoftAsp.NeT4You'

--Return Val
Declare @RetCapWord varchar(100)
Set @RetCapWord=''

;WITH CTE AS
(
    Select @Val As oldVal,1 As TotalLen,SUBSTRING(@Val,1,1) As newVal,
    ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Val,1,1)) As AsciVal

    UNION ALL

    Select oldVal,TotalLen+1 As TotalLen,
    substring(@Val,TotalLen+1,1) As newVal,
    ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Val,TotalLen+1,1)) As AsciVal
    From CTE
    where CTE.TotalLen<=LEN(@Val)
)
Select @RetCapWord=@RetCapWord+newVal
From CTE
Inner Join master..spt_values as m on CTE.AsciVal=m.number and CTE.AsciVal between 65 and 90

Select @RetCapWord
```