# SELECT Only the words that are capitalized

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column called `Cities`, this column has data as the following:

```
 City 1
 CITY 1         
 CITY 1
```

I want to Select only the `CITY` (Capitalized)

This is not doing the job:

```
SELECT * FROM Location
WHERE Cities LIKE 'CITY 1'
```

This is giving me all the `CITY 1` includes `City 1`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Locate upper case characters in SQL Server database field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160476/locate-upper-case-characters-in-sql-server-database-field)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, SQL Server will use a case insensitive collation.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Location 
WHERE Cities LIKE 'CITY 1' 
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI
```

Mark your comparison operator with a case-sensitive collation to apply a case sensitive filter

Answer (score 1):

I assume your SQL is in a non case-sensitive collation in which case a search for 'C' and 'c' will return the same result. You need to do a case-sensitive search by collating the query:

```
SELECT * FROM Location WHERE Cities LIKE 'CITY 1' COLLATE <Insert case sensitive collation here>
```

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM Location WHERE Cities LIKE 'CITY 1' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BINARY operator to enforce case sensitivity.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html

```
SELECT * FROM Location WHERE BINARY Cities = 'CITY 1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM Location
WHERE Cities COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'CITY 1'
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```
Select * From Location Where Cities=BINARY UPPER(Cities);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this query.

```
SELECT *
FROM Location
WHERE Cities LIKE 'CITY 1'
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

The collate makes the query case sensitive 'CS' and accent sensitive 'AS'. The Latin1 specifies English among many other languages.

Comment: (Edit) True, though there is no point using `like` without a wildcard. Just use `=`.  Also, this was already suggested several times. So no need to post it again :)