# Locate and create a list of all entries that contain uppercase

Tags: sql, ms-access

To give you an understanding of the situation, I've got a field that stores Email Addresses and I need to find any email addresses that contain uppercase characters, so ideally I need a query that will find any occurrences and display a full list but not make any changes. I have attempted to find something like this already but unfortunately not located anything similar.

The field name is 'sEmailAddress' and the table is called 'Buyer'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160476/locate-upper-case-characters-in-sql-server-database-field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *StrComp*:

```
Select *
From Buyer
Where StrComp(LCase(sEmailAddress), sEmailAddres, 0) <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBA function like this in WHERE clause:

```
Public Function HasUppercase(str As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    If IsNull(str) Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        If Asc(Mid(str, i, 1)) <= 90 Then
            HasUppercase = True
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE HasUppercase([field1])=True;
```

Comment: You're assuming that the string only contails letters. Even if it contains a space, your function will return true. Add `AND Asc(Mid(str, i, 1)) > 64` to handle any input.